# How to call function when a certain date arrives

Tags: laravel

I have an `API` (made with `Laravel`) for an `iOS` app that is an events manager where the users have some kind of points for going to the events and if they say they will go but then they do not end up going I have to take out some points.

So my question is how can I call the function below when the event has passed to take out the points.

```
public function takePoints(){
    
    $postUser = post_user::where('posts_id', '=', $id);

    foreach ($postUser as $post){
        if($post->state){
            $user = User::where('id', '=', $postUser->user_id);
            
            $user->points -= 50;
            
            $user->saveOrFail();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically something like:

```
if($post->date = $todaysDate){
  $this->takePoints()
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [PHP Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)?

Comment: `$this.takePoints()` is JS syntax, probably need to use `$this->takePoints()` to actually call the function. That aside, this sounds like a job for a CRON task. It'll run every minute, hour, day, etc and perform the check, executing the action should it pass the condition. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling for more information.

Comment: yeah, my bad.I'll check it out thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use Laravel's task scheduling to run periodic checks and perform an operation when a specified time has passed.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

This runs on top of `cron` and allows you to create commands that are run at time periods you define within the console kernel.

```
// add this to cron to run every minute
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

And from within the kernel you can schedules tasks:

```
$schedule->job(new Heartbeat)->everyFiveMinutes();
```